# compare datetime with date and time

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have currently two table like this : 
[image] 
And I want to compare my Datetime(table2) with my column date and time with only one condition but this doesn't work :

```
SELECT id
FROM Table1
WHERE Date+Time>(SELECT Datetime FROM Table2 WHERE Id=1)
AND Id=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the following two should work out just fine.

```
select id from table1
where concat(date,' ',time) > (select datetime from table2 where id = 1)
and id = 1;
```

or

```
select t1.id from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2
on t1.id = t2.id and concat(t1.date,' ',t1.time) > t2.datetime;
```

There is a possibility that you might need explicit conversion of time and date columns to char. I doubt it, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Id
FROM Table1
WHERE CAST(Date as DATETIME) + CAST(Time as TIME)>= (SELECT Datetime FROM Table2 WHERE Id=1)
AND Id=1
```

But note you won´t get a result as far as your date is equal and you use ">" for your query.